# Tengo un problema estoy intentando colocar en mi clase startup.cs un app.UseMvc Pero me sale el siguiente error CS1061

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

"IRouteBuilder" no contiene una definición para "MapSpaFallbackRoute" ni un método de extensión accesible "MapSpaFallbackRoute" que acepte un primer argumento del tipo "IRouteBuilder" (¿falta alguna directiva using o una referencia de ensamblado?

```
 app.UseMvc(routes => {
            routes.MapRoute(name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            routes.MapSpaFallbackRoute(
            name: "spa-fallback",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" });
        });
```

Comment: ¿Has instalado el pkg *Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices*? Este método está en el *namespace* `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder`?

Comment: no no lo tengo instalado

Comment: Ya lo instale mi quito el error pero me aparece esta Advertencia MVC1005 Using 'UseMvc' to configure MVC is not supported while using Endpoint Routing. To continue using 'UseMvc', please set 'MvcOptions.EnableEndpointRouting = false' inside 'ConfigureServices'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tuve que instalar la Libreria de *Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices* y utilizar en mi servicio la siguiente linea de codigo

```
        services.AddMvc(option => option.EnableEndpointRouting = false);
```